# Django many-to-many through query simplification?

Tags: django

I have a `Project`, `User` and a many-to-many through table called `ProjectMembership`:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    '''Project model
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='ProjectMembership'
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
    )

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
    )
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(
        Project,
        through=ProjectMembership
    )

class ProjectMembership(models.Model):
    '''Project Membership model
    '''
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_project_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I want a list of all the active project managers on all the active projects that a specific user is on. I have used the following query and loops below, but perhaps there is a way to do this without the loops?

```
    projects = self.leave_not_required_user.projects.filter(is_active=True)
    users = []
    for project in projects:
        project_memberships = project.projectmembership_set.filter(
            is_project_manager=True,
            user__is_active=True
        ).all()
        for project_membership in project_memberships:
            users.append(project_membership.user)
```

Comment: The indentation in the second code block is erroneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
memberships = ProjectMembership.objects.filter(
     user__is_active=True, is_project_manager=True,      
     project__is_active=True
)

users = [membership.user for membership in memberships]
```